# prove an inequality on the norm.

Tags: sequences-and-series

My textbook says that "obvious estimates show that"
$$\Biggl|\Biggl|\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n e^{int}\left(1-\frac{\sin(\pi \delta_n)}{\pi \delta_n}\right)\Biggr|\Biggr|\leq 1-\frac{\sin(\pi L)}{\pi L}$$
under the assumptions
$$\sum_n|c_n|^2\leq 1$$
$$|\delta_n|\leq L< 1/4$$
Now I'm trying to prove the inequality. I applied Hölder's inequality and:
$$\Biggl|\Biggl|\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n e^{int}\left(1-\frac{\sin(\pi \delta_n)}{\pi \delta_n}\right)\Biggr|\Biggr|\leq \sqrt{ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \Bigl|1-\frac{\sin(\pi \delta_n)}{\pi \delta_n}\Bigr|^2} $$
But now I do not know go on. Any suggestions please?

Comment: what is $||x||$? $|x|$ is absolute value? then isn't that two times a little redundant?

Comment: $||x||$ norm, $|x|$ absolute value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sum |c_n|^2 \leq 1$ and $|e^{int}| < 1$.

Now another observation is : $$ 1 - \frac {\sin {\pi x}} {\pi x}$$ is increasing in the interval in the interval $0 < x \leq \frac{1}{4}$ for the fact that the derivative is positive.

So the upper bound can be set by evaluating at $x = L$.

Comment: You could do all the steps please? For me, these steps are not obvious.

Comment: Which part is not clear to you ? I can add in the comment.

Comment: I can explain you better when you tell me exactly what is $\|.\|$ here and whether n varies from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ ? My guess is you are talking about the averaged $L^2([0,2\pi])$ wrt variable $t$ ? But nothing changes in the answer, because the estimates are correct. I was wrong in saying the norm is Euclidean, it makes no sense, sorry.

Comment: Sorry for the bad English, maybe you could help me by adding all the details that you consider appropriate.

Comment: Can you tell me which text book and the page number on which this problem is there ? Will help.

Comment: Robert m. Young "An introduction to non harmonic fourier series", page 37, proof of Kadec's 1/4 theorem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13573/discussion-between-mark-and-diffeor)